# What is the ZeroMQ PUB/SUB internal behaviour?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe, distributed-computing, pyzmq, low-latency

I'm trying to get my head around to the behaviour of **`zmq`** with **`PUB/SUB`**.

**`Q1:`** I can't find a real reason why with the **`PUSH/PULL`** sockets combo I can create a queue that actually queue in memory messages that it can't get delivered (the consumer is not available) when with the **`PUB/SUB`** not.

**`Q2:`** Is there any technical whitepaper or document that describes in detail the internals of the sockets?

**EDIT:**
This example of [PUSH/PULL streamer](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/streamer.html) works as expected (the worker join late or restart and gets the queued messages in the feeder. [PUB/SUB forwarder](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/forwarder.html) does not behave in the same way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### While `Q1` is hard to be answered  / fully addressed without a `SLOC` ...

there is still a chance your ***code***  <sub>( though yet unpublished,
which StackOverflow so much encourages user to include in a form aka `MCVE`
and you may already have felt or soon might feel some flames for not doing so )</sub> 
**just
 forgotten** to set a subscription **topic-filter**

```
aSubSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE = "" )          # ->recv "EVERYTHING" / NO-TOPIC-FILTER
aSubSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE = "GOOD-NEWS" ) # ->recv "GOOD-NEWS" MESSAGES to be received only
```

### A2: yes, there are exhaustive descriptions of all ZeroMQ API calls +

besides the [**API manpage** collection for ØMQ/2.1.1 and other versions](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-setsockopt),
there is a great online published **pdf** book **"Code Connected, Vol.1"** from Pieter HINTJENS himself.

Worth reading. A lot of insights into general distributed-processing area and `ZeroMQ` way.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to read that document. I've updated the question with the links of the two architectures I've tried.

Comment: Glad the answer helped. If your MCVE-related trouble continues, rather post the MCVE that demonstrates the failure in a fully repeatable manner. Details what is the internal ZeroMQ PUB/SUB behaviour is well documented in relevant section **[ Publish-subscribe pattern ]** of **http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-socket**